# Iterate through a list of elements and hide them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In javascript (jquery), I'm retrieving a list of elements that start with "#error-". This works correctly. The problem I have is that I can't assign a value to elements of the array while looping through it.

I'm using this function:

```
function HideErrorMessages(){
    var errors = $('*[id^="error-"]');
    for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
        errors[i].css('display', none);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I tried this "css" possibility. Doesn't work.
I also tried:

- errors[i].hide();
- errors[i].style.display = 'none';

But when using " alert(errors[i]) ", I get a response which indicates that it contains a list of "span" elements (which is correct).

So how can I do to hide elements in this loop?

Thanks!

Comment: if errors[i] is also a list you need to loop through that as well. Also just a tip, `console.log` is generally preferred over `alert`

Comment: `errors[i]` will return DOM node, try `errors.eq(i).css('display', 'none')` also you call css with `none` instead of `'none'`, which should throw exception that none is undefined.

Comment: @mjr errors is a list of html elements (span). It is not a list of lists. errors[i] should be the element itself, unless I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`errors[i]` makes reference to a property inside the jQuery object which is a selected DOM object. There's no `css` function for those objects, it's a jQuery thing. But you can use jQuery [`eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to select the object and have access to jQuery methods:

```
errors.eq(i).css('display', 'none');
```

You can also use [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate each element of the jQuery object:

```
$('*[id^="error-"]').each(function(){
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: `.get(i)` will return DOM node, you should use `.eq(i)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Helpful and informational. I ended using the "each" one which worked for my case. The first solution doesn't work, though, so you might want to edit it since I accepted the answer? Anyway, thank you!

Comment: The other solution should also work. You said you tried `errors[i].hide()` in your question, which isn't exactly what the answer implied. `hide` will take the list of all elements in the jQuery object and hide them. If you use exactly what the answer provided (without any loop) then it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Try to invoke `.hide()` over the jquery object,

```
$('[id^="error-"]').hide();
```

You don't need to iterate over that elements one by one. If you fetch elements from a jquery object by bracket notation, then it will return native javascript DOM node. So `.css()` will cause error as it is not a part of a DOM node.

Comment: Doesn't work. I get the same problem: the script stops working. I see no other possibility than a problem of syntax, but I don't know this language enough to tell what is wrong.

Comment: @zuokuok This should work. Are you seeing any errors in console?

Comment: @ Rajaprabhy The problem is that the script doesn't work. My knowledge of javascript is too limited to tell you why, but this syntax doesn't do it for me. I ended up using the solution below which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would go like this.

```css
$('#buttonClick').on('click', function() {
  var showing = $(this).closest('.thumbBrowser').find('ul li:visible');
  var next = showing.last().next();
  if( next.length === 0 ) {
    next = $(this).closest('.thumbBrowser').find('ul li').first();
  }
  next.toggleClass('hidden').next().toggleClass('hidden');
  showing.toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbBrowser">
          <ul>
            <li class="thumbLeft caseStudy tint tintWhite">
              <a href="client-page.html"><img src="images/argus_thumb.jpg" alt="one"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="thumbRight caseStudy tint">
              <img src="images/adr_thumb.jpg" alt="two">
            </li>
            <li class="hidden thumbLeft caseStudy tint tintWhite">
              <img src="images/dd_thumb.jpg" alt="three">
            </li>
            <li class="hidden thumbRight caseStudy tint">
              <img src="images/cdp_thumb.jpg" alt="four">
            </li>
             <li class="hidden thumbRight caseStudy tint tintWhite">
              <a href="client-page.html"><img src="images/pm_thumb.jpg" alt="five"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="hidden thumbLeft caseStudy tint tintWhite">
              <img src="images/argus_thumb.jpg" alt="six">
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="cycleButton" id="buttonClick"><img src="images/cycleIcon.png"></div>
    </div>
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```